# How to data-bind TreeViewItem.IsExpanded to a node data objects

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, treeview, silverlight-toolkit

I have a hierarchical data classes like

```
public class MyNode 
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public bool IsExpanded { get; set;}
   public List<MyNode> Nodes { get; set;}
}
```

I could define a HierarchicalDataTemplate to bind MyNode classes to the TreeView.

```
<sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}">
  <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</sdk:TreeView>
```

The question is how to data-bind IsExpanded property of TreeViewItem to corresponding MyNode.IsExpanded property, so I could persist this information.

Thank you in advance,
Lex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, if we override TreeView & TreeViewItem classes like this:

```
public class ExTreeView : System.Windows.Controls.TreeView
{
  protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
  {
    return new ExTreeViewItem();
  }
}
```

public class ExTreeViewItem : System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem
{
  public ExTreeViewItem()
  {
    SetBinding(IsExpandedProperty, new Binding("IsExpanded") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
  }

protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
  {
    return new ExTreeViewItem();
  }
}

Then use ExTreeView instead of TreeView, it will automatically data bind to IsExpanded property of hierarchical data item.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this works in Silverlight or not, but in WPF you can bind to `IsExpanded` by using a style:

```
<sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}">
    <sdk:TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </sdk:TreeView.Resources>
    <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</sdk:TreeView>
```

Comment: That was also my first guess :)

But no, it does not work in Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

I had to cope with the same issue and I did the MVVM way.

First, you want to create a property that will represent whether the item is expanded or not in your view-model (that's mainly where MVVM helps you out).

In your node's view-model simply add something like `Boolean IsNodeExpanded { get; set; }`.
Warning: The above is just the interface! you must notify changes with `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`, **otherwise it will not work!**

Next you want to hook it up to your view and this is very similar to what Andy here suggested; use styles. However his markup wasn't enough for me (one reason is that it didn't work).
 
What you actually want to do is place the style in the tree-view's `ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<TreeView ...>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsNodeExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

And this did work for me in my case.

---

*Note 1: Save yourself a headache, and make sure the binding in the style above is a **two-way** binding as it is presented. I had a project some time ago when I had to re-do this, I forgot to make it a two-way, and even debugging didn't help.*

*Note 2: You should use MVVM for this function, I have tried to use code-behind for it because it seemed shorter (I'm lazy) and it turned out to be a long mess, and not just because it requires a recursive function, also because hidden items don't seem to exist until their parent is opened. **It's not pleasant**, and it may seem like a quick way to do it, but my experience made it much longer.*